# How to make an android app written in jQuery Mobile and Phonegap

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-build

Im new to web development and app development. I can make apps using html5 and css3 with no problem. But when i use jquery mobile the app doesnt display properly. How can i fix it. This is the code i have used

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Test App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_assets/css/jqm-demos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/glyphish.css.css">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700"> -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="_assets/js/index.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"
    src="cordova/cordova.js"></script>
    <style>
    .background {background:url(_assets/img/background.jpg)}
    .toparea {background:#FFF}
    .toparea { padding-top: 0.2px !important; padding-bottom: 0.2px !important }
    .toparea {alignment-adjust:middle !important; }
    </style>
    <style>
        .nav-glyphish-example .ui-btn .ui-btn-inner { padding-top: 40px !important; }
        .nav-glyphish-example .ui-btn .ui-icon { width: 30px!important; height: 30px!important; margin-left: -15px !important; box-shadow: none!important; -moz-box-shadow: none!important; -webkit-box-shadow: none!important; -webkit-border-radius: 0 !important; border-radius: 0 !important; }
        #chat .ui-icon { background:  url(_assets/img/glyphish-icons/53-house.png) 50% 50% no-repeat; background-size: 22px 22px; }
        #email .ui-icon { background:  url(_assets/img/glyphish-icons/157-wrench.png) 50% 50% no-repeat; background-size: 24px 24px;  }
        #login .ui-icon { background:  url(_assets/img/glyphish-icons/42-photos.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;  background-size: 22px 24px; }
        #beer .ui-icon { background:  url(_assets/img/glyphish-icons/80-shopping-cart.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;  background-size: 26px 19px; }
        #coffee .ui-icon { background:  url(_assets/img/glyphish-icons/18-envelope.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;  background-size: 24px 16px; }
    </style>    
</head>
<body>


<section data-role="page" class="background" id="home">
     <div class="toparea" data-theme="d" data-position="persistent">
        <h1>Test App</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-theme="d" data-role="footer" class="nav-glyphish-example" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar" class="nav-glyphish-example" data-grid="d">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" class="ui-btn-active" data-transition="flow" id="chat" data-icon="custom"></a></li>
                <li><a href="services.html" data-transition="flow" id="email" data-icon="custom"></a></li>
                <li><a href="gallery.html" data-transition="flow" id="login" data-icon="custom"></a></li>
                <li><a href="products.html" data-transition="flow" id="beer" data-icon="custom"></a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html" data-transition="flow" id="coffee" data-icon="custom"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope that you can help me.

Regards

Michael

Comment: hi whether ur posted code is not running r ur asking for steps for jQM + Phonegap app to get started..please be clear

Comment: what exactly does not display properly? can you post the desired output vs. what you're seeing? what JQM version are you using? what PhoneGap version? what mobile phone you're testing it on? does it work on the Emulator? what SDK do you use to deploy? what socks color are you wearing today?

Answer (score 0):

> > Steps for create android app using PhoneGap:

```
1) Download latest phongap(cordova) zip file.
2) Paste cordova.js file in www folder and link in index.html .
3) Paste www folder in /Projectname/assets folder.
4) Paste cordova-x.x.x.jar file in /Projectname/libs folder.
5) Paste xml folder(which contain config.xml) in /Projectname/res folder.
6) Add following code in /Projectname/AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"
/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"
/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

 7)  Add following code in /Projectname/src/com/example/packagename/MainActivity.java file.

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

    public MainActivity() {
    super();
    }       
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    //init webview
    this.init();        
     // Clear our cache (this is used mainly during development - comment out for production)
    this.clearCache();      
     // Show splashscreen
    //this.setIntegerProperty("Splashscreen",R.drawable.bg_splash);
    this.setIntegerProperty("Splashscreen",R.drawable.ic_launcher); 
    // Load our app
       this.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html",3000);

    }
}
 8) Finally get compiled application package file(.apk file) from Projectname/bin folder.
```

Answer (score 0):

For me (phonegap 3.x + android 4.2) the glyphish icons won't show up on device although they render fine on my windows laptop.

I managed to get it showing by avoiding the underscore (_) preceding the "_asset" folder. That is,

1. Rename **"_asset**" folder name to "**asset**" using file manager.
2. Edit the CSS code from "**url(_asset/img/....**" to "**url(asset/img/....**" in order to match the earlier folder name change.